# get "angular is not defined" when adding to Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I added the following function to Object.prototype:

```
Object.prototype.clearAllProperties = function () {
                Object.keys(this).forEach(function (key) { delete this[key] })
            };
```

I was hoping to use it like `object.clearAllProperties();`

However I now get a bunch of angular is not defined errors as well as JQuery errors. Is this because I am overwriting some function on Object already? Is adding to a javascript defined prototype a bad idea in general?

Comment: If you wish to "clear" an object, simply assign an empty object to it `{}`

Comment: @callmekatootie and what do I do about other references to that object (I want them to also point to the cleared object)?